# MS Access - Dlookup to set value of field based on content of another table

Tags: ms-access, lookup

I'm a newbie to Access.
I have two tables.
The first is called **Dates** - it has 3 columns (apart from the key) which are:

*From Date* (e.g. 01/07/2017)

*To Date* (e.g. 30/09/2017)

*Period* (e.g. 2017-2018 Q1)

The second table is called **Expenses**, and it has many columns, two of which are *Expense Date* and *Period*.

*Expense Date* is input by the user.

I want *Period* to be filled via a `DLookup` function from the **Dates** table based on the *Expense Date*, e.g. (using Excel syntax)

```
`DLOOKUP(["From Date":"To Date","Expense Date","Period")`
```

I am assuming this function would need to be written in Row Source under the Lookup tab of the Expenses design view.

Would anyone be able to tell me what is the correct syntax for Access and where I should write the required function?

Answer (score 0):

No, you would not use a DLookup in the RowSource. You would use an SQL statement.

A DLookup() expression can be used in the ControlSource property of a textbox or in Field cell of query design view.

In this case the expression would be:

`DLookup("Period", "Dates", "#" & [Expense Date] & "# BETWEEN [From Date] AND [To Date]")`

If you are using international dates, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html. Gustav's suggestion for formatting the data may be needed.

Refer to Access Help or Google search to learn more about domain aggregate functions.

Advise no spaces nor punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in names.

Comment: Thanks June.  I added that expression into the ControlSource, but there is no effect.  When I input a date, the Period stays blank.

Comment: See revised answer to use # delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form bound to table *Expenses*, you would use the *AfterUpdate* event of the textbox bound to field *Expense Date* (here named TextExpenseDate):

```
Private Sub TextExpenseDate_AfterUpdate()

    If IsNull(Me!TextExpenseDate.Value) Then
        Me!Period.Value = Null
    Else
        Me!Period.Value = DLookup("Period", "Dates", "#" & Format(Me!TextExpenseDate.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# Between [From Date] And [To Date]")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav. I tried this in both fields, but it throws errors. Either invalid entry or some other error which I can't reproduce.  I suspect there is a problem with binding as the field for Period says "unbound". I'll have to do more research about access. It seems more complicated than I anticipated. Thanks nonetheless.

Comment: No VBA should be required. The DLookup in ControlSource should recalculate when the [Expense Date] textbox is updated. It works for me. Just a matter of getting the expression syntax and textbox referencing correct.